# Install local package using setup.py

Tags: python, installation, package, setup.py

Using swagger.io's editor I have generater a API client from a provided swagger file.
In pycharm I have then created a new project with own virtual environment adn wishes to install the generated client and work from there.
So that I have a "main" file ala (only illustrative):

```
import swagger_client
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import pandas as pd
data = swagger_client.get()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
... 
results = df
```

Right now i just placed the python-clinet folder in my main folder for the project:

```
C:\Users\(username)\PycharmProjects\API\
```

This python-client folder contains a the client generated from the swaggerfile and includes the requriment.txt and setup.py files along with a swagger-client folder which contains the actual client I need to install (I assume).

I have mostly just worked within a actual script in pycharm and know that i need to work on my skillset above just the py file im working in.

So how do I from here install the python client the easiest way.
Online searches give a lot of answers I find unfit, but that may be because of my limited skillset. So please dump it a bit down.

BR

Answer (score 0):

Okay to quick asking for help.

In the pycharm terminal (not console) I wrote:

```
python -m pip install -e C:\Users\(user_name)\PycharmProjects\API\python-client
```